# How to pass selected dropdown value to url query string on the same jsp page

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, drop-down-menu

I have a jsp page say, xyz.jsp . I have a dropdown menu in the page which displays financial years. I want to pass the selected dropdown value to the URL query string.

This is the only method I tried and I dint understand how it works.

`<div id="yeardropdown" class="dropdown" style="margin-top: -60px; float: right; border-radius: 8px;">
  <button class="dropbtn" style ="text-align:center;"></button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <% for (String uniqueFinancialYear :uniqueValues) {%>
    <a><%= uniqueFinancialYear %></a>
    <%} %>
  </div>
</div>`

How to pass the selected value into the URL query string on the same jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the element should be find by class name instead of global selector of 'a' and also corrected the code as follows.

```
 $('.dropdown-content a').on('click', function() {

  window.location.href = window.location.href.split('?')[0] + "?year=" + this["innerHTML"];
});
```

Comment: This works,but the year gets added in chain to query string each time i select an option from dropdown - /safetyschedule.jsp?year=2018-2019?year=2019-2020?year=2018-2019 like this.

Comment: @AmruthaDesai i have updated the answer please check with the same

Answer (score 0):

You can add click event on a tag and use `window.location.href`

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
  window.location.href = window.location.href + "?year=" + this.html();
});
```